# How to use arguments in Makefile in C

Tags: c, makefile, shakespeare-text

I am doing an assignment in C where I need to read in characters from a text file that contains the works of Shakespeare. My professor wants me to do the following: "Write a make file that can compile and run the C program you write. Specifically, when I type

```
$ make run textfile=CompleteShakespeare.txt
```

your program should analyze the text file of `CompleteShakespeare.txt`. I don't really know how to go about this. Is `CompleteShakespeare.txt` inputted as `argv[1]` here? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `make` will do whatever the `Makefile` or `makefile` says to do. You need to create a `makefile`. You can do an internet search on "how to create a makefile". `run` is a "target" and `textfile=CompleteShakespeare.txt` sets the makefile variable `textfile` to "CompleteShakespeare.txt".

Comment: you need the makefile to call the compiler with '-DFILE_PATH=Shakespeare.txt'